# Construct a circle orthogonal to another circle and tangent to a given line

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-construction

This is a though one.

[image]

It seems like the locus of the centers $B$ of the desired circles all lie in a parabola. How to figure a nice simple way to construct those circles with ruler and compass?

I take it all back: the locus is not a parabola even though it looks like one from the distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Gamma$ and $\ell$ the initial circumference and line, respectively.

Choose any point $P\in\Gamma$. If you want the circles to be orthogonal in $P$, draw the line $\ell_1$ that joins the center of $\Gamma$ with $P$ and its perpendicular $\ell_2$ that passes through $P$.

Now, let $O=\ell_1\cap\ell$ (possibly infinity point). Note that $OP=OQ$, where $Q$ is the point where the circle you want to build will be tangent to $\ell$ (you can find $Q$ drawing a circle with center $O$ and radius $OP$).

Whit this, the perpendicular to $\ell$ through $Q$ must intersect $\ell_2$ at the center of the circle you want.

Comment: What if we started with a point in the line?